# Juypter will not launch from Anaconda

Tags: python

When launching Juypter from Anaconda I receive the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\Users\ceo20\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
>       from notebook.notebookapp import main
>       File "C:\Users\ceo20\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 80, in 
>       from .services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager
>       File "C:\Users\ceo20\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 19, in 
>       from jupyter_client.session import Session
>       File "C:\Users\ceo20\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client__init__.py", line 4, in 
>       from .connect import *
>       File "C:\Users\ceo20\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 35, in 
>       from jupyter_core.paths import jupyter_data_dir, jupyter_runtime_dir, secure_write
>       ImportError: cannot import name 'secure_write' from 'jupyter_core.paths' (C:\Users\ceo20\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hey,
Did you happen to have python installed before installing conda? Could be something messes things up. Is your conda linked to your path? If not try to add this to path and access to jupyter from cli

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install --upgrade jupyter_client
```

This package provides the Python API for starting, managing and communicating with Jupyter kernels. The above code will upgrade jupyter client.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Anaconda prompt

```
pip install --upgrade jupyter_client
```